# i cant run flutter project in android studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I bought the source code of an app that was written with a flutter framework After implementing it on Android Studio I encountered this problem That the Android Studios run button has been disabled and I can't run the project.
You can see more details in the photo below.

[image]

Comment: Have you set up your android studio according to recommendations? https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/editor ?

Comment: Start an emulator or simulator. Then it will show the device on that device name list and the play button will be enabled.